# Use GraphQL data in gatsby-browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I have an app with some route ID's (basically a bunch of sections in a long SPA) that I have defined manually. I fetch these in `gatsby-browser.js` and use them in conjunction with `shouldUpdateScroll`, checking if the route ID exist, and in that case, scroll to the position of the route/section.

Example:

```
export const shouldUpdateScroll = ({ routerProps: { location } }) => {
  const container = document.querySelector('.site')
  const { pathname } = location
  
  const projectRoutes = [`project1`, `project2`]
  if (projectRoutes.indexOf(pathname) !== -1) {
      const target = document.getElementById(pathname)
      container.scrollTop = target.offsetTop; 
  }

  return false
}
```

This works well for my usecase.

Now I want to add something similar for a page where the content is dynamically created (fetched from Sanity). From what I understand I cannot use GraphQL in `gatsby-browser.js`, so what is the best way to get the ID's from Sanity to `gatsby-browser.js` so I can use them to identify their scroll positions?

If there's some other better way to achieve the same result I'm open to that of course.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are over complexing the issue. You don't need the `gatsby-browser.js` to achieve it.

- First of all, because you are accessing directly to the DOM objects (using `document.getElementById`) and you are creating precisely a virtual DOM with React to avoid pointing the real DOM. Attacking directly the real DOM (like jQuery does) has a huge performance impact in your applications and may cause some issues since in the SSR (**S**erver-**S**ide **R**endering) the element may not be created yet.
- You are hardcoding a logic part (the `id`s) on a file that is not intended to do so.

I think you can achieve exactly the same result using a simple function using a few hooks.

You can get the same information as `document.getElementById` using [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook and scrolling to that position once needed.

```
const YourComponent= (props) => {
  const sectionOne = useRef(null);
  const sectionTwo = useRef(null);

  useEffect(()=>{
   if(typeof window !== `undefined`){
    console.log("sectionOne data ",sectionOne.current)
    console.log("sectionTwo data ",sectionTwo.current)
      if(sectionOne) window.scrollTo( 0, 1000 ); // insert logic and coordinates 
   }
  }, [])   

  return (
    <>
      <section ref={sectionOne}>Section 1</section>
      <section ref={sectionTwo}>Section 2</section>
    </>
  );
}
```

You can isolate that function into a separate file in order to receive some parameters and return some others to achieve what you want. Basically, the snippet above creates a reference for each section and, once the DOM tree is loaded (`useEffect` with empty `deps`, `[]`) do some stuff based on your logic.

Your `document.getElementById` is replaced for `sectionOne.current` (note the `.current`), initially set as `null` to avoid unmounting or cache issues when re-hidration occurs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your suggestion makes sense. I've gradually rewritten how my app works and at this point maybe I should favor a total rewrite in the way you suggest. I'll be taking a stab at it ASAP to see if I can achieve what I need. I'll revisit your answer and mark it as the solution once I do. Thanks again!

Comment: Nice. Keep in mind to use the `typeof window !== 'undefined'` when using global objects. You can find more details in https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/

Comment: The menu I use to navigate to these sections is global, so I can be on another page and click the project name in the menu and it should change route and identify and go to that section. What do you reckon, should I have a state in a HoC/context that saves the ID of the menu item that is clicked that then is acted upon when route has changed?